# google app engine email attachment: download it to file system

Tags: python, google-app-engine, download, email-attachments

I am able to receive an email to app engine. I see the data in an attachment is payload base64 encoded data. Can I download the attachment as it is to file system without processing it or without storing it to blobstore?

Comment: @Bastian, by filesystem I mean to say downloading it locally on the machine(where code executes).

Comment: can I give path to a local directory to get attchment saved there?

Comment: you can't write to a file in app engine

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write a File to your web application directory in App Engine.

Possible choices for you are:

- Save the content in the Datastore.
- Use the Blobstore
- Use the Google Storage facility.

Alternately, you might want to post the content away to an external server that can store the data, either your own or some 3rd party like Amazon S3.